# Is there any way to run 64bit Virtual Machine on 64bit processor without hardware virtualization (amd-v, vt-x)?

Tags: hardware, vmware, virtualization, virtualbox, openvz

We have a 64bit virtual machine (CentOS) that we'd like to run on 64bit host-machine (may be running under any OS), but that host-machine doesn't support hardware virtualization, which, you know, should be for running 64bit virtual machines in it.

I tried VirtualBox and VMware Player, but they both have this issue with non-hardware-virtualization processor. I thought maybe another virtualization system may help, like OpenVZ or XEN or KVM? What do you think?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not programming-related - belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running x86-64 ASM on a x86-32 processor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266044/running-x86-64-asm-on-a-x86-32-processor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qemu http://www.qemu.org/ can virtualise architectures without hardware support (even ARM, MIPS, etc). However, it will probably be a lot slower than using qemu-kvm with virtualisation hardware.

Comment: "Slow" is not such a big problem in our case :) Will try Qemu. Thank you!